# Sorting objects by it's value

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have a dynamic object like this:

```
{
  AB = "18722";
  CF = "345555.4";
  DT = "87789.33";
}
```

And I need to sort it by it's value in descending format.

I have searched for this but most answers I found have static key, which doesn't work in my case.

Comment: What output are you expecting? An array of values? You can't "sort" an object, its keys are unordered by definition in JavaScript.

Comment: You mean the object properties themselves should be sorted? If so, take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value

Comment: That's also invalid JS, btw.

Comment: @andy: no, it's valid. But it's not an object literal.